# Delete original image from cloudinary

Tags: node.js, image, cloudinary

I am using cloudinary with node and multer
I successfully managed to store images but i noticed each time i upload an image it creates two copies : one with the public_id as a name (in the assets) and the other with the original name(in 'profiles' folder).

I want to delete both whenever i upload a new image but it only deletes the one in the assets and don't delete the one in the 'profiles' picture.

My upload route looks like this

```
import path from "path";
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cloudinary from "cloudinary";
import { CloudinaryStorage } from "multer-storage-cloudinary";
import multer from "multer";

dotenv.config();

const cloud = cloudinary.v2;
const router = express.Router();

cloud.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary: cloud, 
  params: {
    folder: "profiles",
    transformation: { gravity: "center", height: 300, width: 300, crop: "fill" },
    public_id: (req, file) =>
      `${file.originalname.split(".")[0]}-${Date.now()}`,
  },
});

function checkFileType(file, cb) {
  const filetypes = /jpg|jpeg|png/;
  const extname = filetypes.test(
    path.extname(file.originalname).toLocaleLowerCase()
  );
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
  if (extname && mimetype) {
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
}

const upload = multer({
  storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
});

router.post("/", upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await cloud.uploader.upload(req.file.path)
    res.send(result);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});

export default router;
```

And the delete route

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cloudinary from "cloudinary";

dotenv.config();

const cloud = cloudinary.v2;
const router = express.Router();

cloud.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

router.post('/:id', async (req, res) =>{
    try {
        await cloud.uploader.destroy(req.params.id);
        // await cloud.uploader.destroy(`/profiles/${req.params.id}`);

        res.send(result);
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
    }
    
})

export default router;
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Cloudinary supports only one upload with a single call to the Upload API and I see only one post in the code so I am not sure how it is getting uploaded twice.
If you would like to delete multiple images then you can do so by passing their unique public_id's and invoking the destroy API for every one of them. Since the two uploaded files have different public_id's (public_id also includes folder name if the resource is inside the folder) you will have to invoke the destroy API twice with the unique names to delete both the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone face the same issue
I was sending the image twice in the upload route
Just change it to this

```
router.post("/", upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.json(req.file);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```